# WPF MaterialDesignThemes background color overwrite

Tags: wpf, xaml

Im using a Treeview and I want to change the color of a TreeViewItems on trigger. (This code obviously doensnt work but this is the idea of what i want to do).

Code :

```
    <Style x:Key="TaskStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TreeViewItem}}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsOK}" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#7FF90000"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>  
   </Style>
```

I apply this style like that :

```
<TreeView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TaskStyle}">
    ...
</TreeView>
```

How can I do that since I dont want to overwrite all the TreeViewItem Template style ?

Comment: Get the source code ( well, markup in this case ).  Change it to taste. There'll be a shed load of the stuff but search'll work.

Comment: Its a bit sad to do this only for a background color, but ye

Comment: Maybe when you look in there, you'll see another way that's more elegant. The worst that's going to happen is you learn a bit more about the theme you've chosen. In my experience, a fair few of these things have some rather iffy parts to em.  This is the price you pay for free software. It's also free of any support. Never used material design so this could be much more professional than the rest.